# Size of class with virtual function adds extra 4 bytes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
    class NoVirtual {
        int a;
    public:
        void x() const {}
        int i() const { return 1; }
    };

    class OneVirtual {
        int a;
    public:
        virtual void x() const {}
        int i() const { return 1; }
    };

    class TwoVirtuals {
        int a;
    public:
        virtual void x() const {}
        virtual int i() const { return 1; }
    };

    int main() {
        cout << "int: " << sizeof(int) << endl;
        cout << "NoVirtual: "
             << sizeof(NoVirtual) << endl;
        cout << "void* : " << sizeof(void*) << endl;
  cout << "OneVirtual: "
       << sizeof(OneVirtual) << endl;
  cout << "TwoVirtuals: "
       << sizeof(TwoVirtuals) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The output is:**

NoVirtual: 4
void* : 8
OneVirtual: 16
TwoVirtuals: 16

**Question is:**

Since OneVirtual and TwoVirtuals class have virtual function, size of class should be sizeof(int) + sizeof(void*) i.e. 12bytes. But size is printed as 16bytes.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You forget about *alignment*. See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/119128)

Comment: You are aware of the added pointer, so [this should enlighten you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) somewhat. It's not a direct answer however, by any means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are compiling on 64bit machines since size of int is 4bytes.Typically for 64bit machines pointer size will be 8 bytes and int size is 4 bytes.To satisfy [Data Alignment requirement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/) to save read cycles
compiler adds extra 4 bytes(padding) hence result is 16bytes where as actual required size is 12 bytes.